# can I run vacuum on live Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, vacuum

We want to clean up some dead tuples from tables in our application PostgreSql RDS instance. So we are planning to run "Vacuum" command (not Vacuum full) on live DB after taking a Snapshot. Does this have any impact on the application? Do we need to have an application downtime to carry out this activity?

Option 1: Vacuum all the tables in one go.

Option 2: Vacuum individual tables with a gap of few seconds.

Comment: Usually Autovacuum is already running. I can’t imagine that anybody would take down an application for normal maintenance background jobs. And yes, it does consume IO, but that shouldn’t be a problem